# Error running Xamarin.iOS on an iPad. Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

does anyone know why this is happening? The solution is new and does not support running it from a physical iPad. I have a valid developer credential

[A123](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgkPH.png) [A125](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB4Ht.png)
[A124](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNRkg.png)

Comment: What is the exact error message? - add that to your question. If you google that error message, what have others said about it?

Comment: Deploy Error: Could not install the application 'C:\Users\Tatha\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\HotRestart\Signing\TabletPractice.iOS.app\out\TabletPractice.iOS.ipa' on the device iPad (6). Details: ApplicationVerificationFailed(3892346901) - Failed to verify code signature of /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.NfOkxI/extracted/Payload/TabletPractice.iOS.app : 0xe8008015 (A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.)

Comment: That's the error bro

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  Do you have a valid provisioning profile?

Comment: I do have valid provisioning credentials. I uploaded a new photo

Comment: Does it work on iOS simulator? Does it work on a physical iPhone? I mean is it only iPad that gives trouble? What iOS version? And googling `ipad Failed to verify code signature - A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found` I see lots of links - none of those give you any clue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.